# Insert unique sequence number based on another column value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this SQL Server 2008 R2 table (t1):

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | type | sequence |
+----+------+----------+
| 1  | 'A'  | 1        |
| 2  | 'A'  | 2        |
| 3  | 'A'  | 3        |
| 4  | 'B'  | 1        |
| 5  | 'B'  | 2        |
| 6  | 'C'  | 1        |
+----+------+----------+
```

For example to insert the next sequence for type 'B' which must be 3, I use:

```
void Add(string type)
{
     int i = db.ExecuteScalar("select coalesce(max(sequence) + 1, 1) from t1 where type='" + type + "'"); 
     db.ExecuteNonQuery("insert into t1 (type, sequence) values ('" + type + "', " + i + ")");
}

Add("B");
```

This works fine, but if two users execute Add("B") exactly at the same time **they will get and insert the same sequence**!

How should I prevent this from occuring?

Comment: Use a stored procedure and do both statements in the same transaction. Table will be locked both writing and reading during the transaction. Therefore no other query would run before yours is completed.

Comment: @Helio thanks or do it by:
DbConnection c = db.Open();
DbTransaction t = c.BeginTransaction();
try { /* select next sequence + insert into t1*/ t.Commit(); } 
catch { t.Rollback(); }

Comment: @Helio 
Which isolation level should I use: **Read Committed**, **Repeatable Read** or **Serializable**?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

you can add a lock statement. And in order to prevent a deadlock you should execute the queries in a task.

```
private static object ExecuteLock = new object();
void Add(string type)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lock(ExecuteLock)
        {
            int i = db.ExecuteScalar("select coalesce(max(sequence) + 1, 1) from t1 where type='" + type + "'"); 
            db.ExecuteNonQuery("insert into t1 (type, sequence) values ('" + type + "', " + i + ")");
        }
    });
}

Add("B");
```

This will only work if both users use the same application and same instance of the application to insert a unique sequence number. If two users use a different application, then this problem needs to be solved at a database level, as is explained in the comments